# Spring thymeleaf limit text output in a th:each loop

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am currently making a school project and is almost done. I have an admin panel where I have listed my blogposts, and I want to limit the text field so when it reaches 150 characters it will break and type 3 dots "..."..

The code for the list is here:

```
 <tr th:each = "blog: ${blogs}">
        <th th:text="${blog.title}" scope="row"></th>
        <td><p th:text="${blog.text}"></p></td>
        <td><p th:text="${blog.author}"></p></td>
        <td><p th:text="${blog.date}"></p></td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/blog/delete/{id}(id=${blog.id})}"class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a><a th:href="@{/blog/update/{id}(id=${blog.id})}" class="btn btn-info ml-2">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
```

I have tried to search on google, but can't find a solution.

Thanks for your help!

/Nick

Comment: thanks for the solution. It worked fine, but I would still like to know the syntax in thymeleaf, because I also want to make a "read more" button on the blogposts, so if the blogpost is beyond 150 characters, you can press read more to see the full blog post

Answer (score 14):

If you dont want to do it by CSS you can do it as follows:

```
<td><p th:text="${#strings.length(blog.text)>150 ? #strings.substring(blog.text,0,150) + '...'} : blog.text"></p></td>
```

EDIT:
After searching more found this easy method:

```
<td><p th:text="${#strings.abbreviate(blog.text,150)} "></p></td>
```

Which is a short hand notation for doing the previous solution. You can find details in [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings).

Comment: This is perfect...it just worked for me out of the box. Many thanks